# TypeError: Cannot read property 'topic' of undefined discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

iam trying to **get the name** and **topic** of a **channel**

can anyone tell me what did i do wrong

```
const rules = bot.channels.cache.get('776828354400747580');
console.log(`${rules} :- ${rules.topic}`)
```

Comment: Is there anything not working with the given code? Are you facing any error message?

Answer (score 0):

you should use the code once your bot is ready:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
    const rules = bot.channels.cache.get('776828354400747580');
    console.log(`${rules} :- ${rules.topic}`)
});
```

So the channel is cached and you can access it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the program is trying to access the 'topic' property of the channel when it's undefined. Are you sure you have the right channel id? It's possible that either the channel id you entered is wrong, or the channel isn't a text channel. As another user suggested, it's also possible that you didn't have the code in the
"on-ready" event.

```
bot.on('ready', () => {
    // Code here
});
```